# Make the UIWebview fill screen

Tags: iphone

How do I make the content in the UIWebView fill the whole screen? The UIWebView fills the iphones width correctly, however I need to doubletap the image in the UIWebview to make it stretch out to the bounds.

Help much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `scalesPageToFit` to `YES` on your UIWebView.

Comment: The body of the web page may be larger than the image width. If you have control over the html code, you could use the viewport meta (as documented in http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW1)